# Stop iOS Books adding Excerpt From on copy

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, copy-paste, books

When I copy from Books and paste in another app, the text I had selected is placed in-between left and right quotation marks, and has a short paragraph added afterwards

> Excerpt From
> Book
> Author
> This material may be protected by copyright

How can I make Books copy and paste only the text I have actually selected?

Comment: Related Q&A about macOS: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/137047/37797